# How to wire the magnetic connector for charging?

Tags: pi-zero-w-2

Not sure how to go about it ,I'm new at this.
The magnetic contact connector
https://www.adafruit.com/product/5359

The battery
https://www.adafruit.com/product/328

How do I wire this to work? Any parts I may need?

Answer (score 0):

The information missing in your question is the charger, including the pinouts for that device. The battery has a pair of wires, one positive (red), one negative (black) which should match the leads from the charger.

The connector you've linked is designed to be soldered into a circuit board with "standard" pin spacing. That's not a strict requirement if you make allowances to prevent shorting, as you could simply solder the wires from the charger to the pins and from the battery to the pins, but a circuit board is going to provide mechanical strength that is a desirable feature of any build.

Adafruit has a [prototyping board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2670) that is representative of the pin spacing for the connector you've linked. Image from linked site.

[image: prototyping board]

Additionally, you'd probably have a second connector that snaps onto the newly created battery connector, to power the device. Considering the SE in which this is posted, one would expect that you want to power a Pi.

This adds one more minor part, the microUSB power plug to be wired to the magnetic connector. Some changes to the wiring will be needed if you intend to keep the charger connected to the battery while the Pi is in use, if that is something that can be done safely.